# error saving data to database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm using Django-models for saving data to database but I have a problem,
a new record has an incorrect id (I need to save some records in a `for` loop)

My error:

> IntegrityError: (1062, u"Duplicate entry '46' for key 'PRIMARY'")

The view:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put `subject` in for loop statment, i think you need to create new subject object every time when need to save different subjects

```
i in range(len(SUBJECTS)):
    subject = Subjects()
    ...
    subject.save()
```